# How to include Matlab code into LaTeX in colour?

Tags: listings, highlighting, matlab

I need Matlab code, e.g. the one here, in LaTeX and in colour (the comment is green, for/if/else/end is blue).

```
% super cooles Programm
i = 1
for i = 1:10
    if i > 3
        i=i+2
    else 
        i=i+1
    end
end
```

I tried

```
`\begin{lstlisting}
code
\end{lstlisting}`
```

this gave me the code, but not in colour.

I tried

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab, frame=single]{\MatlabCodeToLaTeX.m}
```

this gave me the error message, that LaTeX couldn't start the file.

How do I get the code properly colored?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.artefact.tk/software/matlab/highlight/?

Comment: Also, the error with `\lstinputlisting` seems to imply that it just can't find the .m file; are you sure you've got the path correct?

Comment: What does the `MatlabCodeToLaTeX` macro do? File paths use `/`, macros use `\`.

Answer (score 3):

I adapted the example form [TEX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}


\lstset{language=Matlab,%
    %basicstyle=\color{red},
    breaklines=true,%
    morekeywords={matlab2tikz},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
    morekeywords=[2]{1}, keywordstyle=[2]{\color{black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},%
    stringstyle=\color{mylilas},
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},%
    showstringspaces=false,%without this there will be a symbol in the places where there is a space
    numbers=left,%
    numberstyle={\tiny \color{black}},% size of the numbers
    numbersep=9pt, % this defines how far the numbers are from the text
    emph=[1]{for,end,break},emphstyle=[1]\color{red}, %some words to emphasise
    %emph=[2]{word1,word2}, emphstyle=[2]{style},    
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
    % super cooles Programm
    i = 1
    for i = 1:10
    if i > 3
        i=i+2
    else 
        i=i+1
    end
    end
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

PS: next time when there is a latex question try searching TEX first!